# Nouveau vs Nvidia proprietary driver

Tags: nvidia, lts, macbook

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my MacBook Pro mid 2010 and I am having issues installing the Nvidia proprietary drivers for its GeForce 320M GPU. Is nouveau a great option to stick with or shall I continue to struggle installing the proprietary ones?

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.